# Оптимизация запроса в базу данных Postgresql с 10 миллионами записями

Tags: postgresql, оптимизация, оптимизация-запросов

Есть база даных я и делаю 2 запроса при перезагрузки страницы и этот запрос выполняеться около 7 секунд, подскажите как я могу оптимизировать его?

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_year FROM auction_result_values;
SELECT DISTINCT make FROM auction_result_values;
```

структура таблицы, сразу уточню я ставил индексы на данные столбцы которые я ищу, тип у них BTREE, но это особо не помогло, как было 7 секунд так и осталось

```
CREATE TABLE auction_result_values (
id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
auction_ident varchar(32),
id_result bigint,
cdate date,
ctime time without time zone,
week smallint,
year integer,
month smallint,
day_of_week smallint,
make varchar(32),
model varchar(64),
vehicle_year integer,
trim varchar(64),
color varchar(32),
doors varchar(1),
cylinders varchar(2),
fuel varchar(12),
transmission varchar(1),
radio varchar(12),
top varchar(12),
int varchar(12),
drive_wheels varchar(12),
ew varchar(12),
odometer bigint,
price numeric(10,2),
is_excluded boolean,
is_good_deal boolean
);

CREATE INDEX idx_13835784_auction_ident ON auction_result_values USING btree (auction_ident);

CREATE INDEX idx_13835784_id_result ON auction_result_values USING btree (id_result);

ALTER TABLE ONLY auction_result_values
ADD CONSTRAINT auction_result_values_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (auction_ident) REFERENCES auctions(ident) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE ONLY auction_result_values
ADD CONSTRAINT auction_result_values_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_result) REFERENCES auction_results(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: и вы не считаете нужным индексы на вот эти выбираемые в запросах поля повесить?

Comment: Индексы, и убрать distinct, который убивает производительность на корню. Вместо него - array_unique в php. И один запрос, а не два.

Comment: *и убрать distinct, который убивает производительность на корню. Вместо него - array_unique в php.* Ну да... тащить весь массив на клиента и там сортировать да отбирать уники - оно, конечно, быстрее, чем сразу по индексу выбрать уникальные... ну зачем ерунду-то говорить?

Comment: эти индексы относятся совсем к другому, если вы намекаете поставить индексы на колонки которые я ищу, то я ставил и как было 7 секунд так и осталось

Comment: вы сделали два отдельных индекса на каждый столбец свой? наличие индексов не повлияло на время выборки? что-то в это не особо верится.

Comment: так и есть, могу показать, возможно я в чём-то ошибаюсь и просто напросто не могу заметить ошибки

Answer (score 1):

На моём опыте `SELECT DISTINCT` без каких-либо условий
и группировок является признаком недонормализованной схемы. Возьмём,
к примеру, поле `make`. Я так понимаю,
это производитель автомобиля? Это же первый кандидат
на вынос из таблицы! Так что первая
рекомендация — сделайте нормальную схему!

Опять же из опыта могу сказать, что простое добавление индекса
может помочь, а может и нет. Есть как минимум две техники
оптимизации, которые могут
(не) сработать. Первая — использование
`GROUP BY` вместо `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT make FROM t_1 GROUP BY make;
```

Иногда это работает быстрее. Вторая
техника — так называемое разреженное сканирование
индекса
(англ. «[*loose indexscan*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan)»),
который в *PostgreSQL* отсутствует, но эмулируется с помощью
рекурсивных общих табличных выражений (англ. «*recursive common
table expressions*»):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t_2 AS (
  (SELECT make FROM t_1 ORDER BY make LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT
    (
      SELECT CAST(MIN(make) AS CHARACTER VARYING(32))
        FROM t_1
       WHERE make > t_2.make
    )
      FROM t_2
     WHERE t_2.make IS NOT NULL
  )
)
SELECT make
  FROM t_2
 WHERE make IS NOT NULL
;
```

Очевидно, тут уже нужен индекс. Работает медленнее
на небольших данных, но может дать значительный прирост
на больших (до × 20, на моём опыте). Плюс всегда
есть материализованные представления (англ. «*materialised views*»),
но тут уже сами, там нетрудно.

Comment: а при чем тут нормализованность схемы, и `distinct` ? ну да, вынести в таблице производителей очевидно можно, и, наверное, нужно, но от `distinct` это никак не спасет, поскольку для выборки существующих данных (а не всей номенклатуры) потребуется делать `join` и все тот же `distinct`

Comment: В случае ОПа существующие данные и вся номенклатура — одно и то же, и я исходил из этого.  Плюс есть триггеры, как отметил коллега под ником «Мелкий» в соседнем ответе.  Тут уже всё зависит от решаемой ОПом задачи.

Comment: совершенно не одно. вы ему предлагаете сгенерить таблицу и делать выборку оттуда. Но если он удалит записи из  основной, то в номенклатуре они останутся. в общем говоря, заявлять что `distinct` является флагом отсутствия нормализованности в БД - ошибчно.

Answer (score 1):

Не делать такие запросы.

На момент релиза 13 версии postgresql не умеет автоматически выполнять [loose indexscan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan). Собственно индекс и вовсе не используется. А потому поиск малого числа уникальных записей среди многих миллионов неэффективен даже при наличии индекса.

Можно научить делать loose indexscan вручную: вместо запроса

```
select
  distinct author_id
from b_p_t
```

Написать

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
(SELECT author_id AS _author_id FROM b_p_t ORDER BY author_id LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT author_id AS _author_id FROM t, LATERAL (
  --find the next author_id > current author_id
  SELECT author_id FROM b_p_t WHERE author_id>t._author_id
  ORDER BY author_id LIMIT 1
) AS a_id
)
SELECT _author_id FROM t;
```

Что выглядит устрашающе, ещё более впечатляюще в explain, но работает на порядки быстрее `distinct` при наличии индекса. ([пример запроса с доклада](https://pgday.ru/ru/2017/papers/232))

---

Или вовсе пересмотреть задачу. Для чего эти данные нужны, может быть их кэшировать и обновлять кэш в фоне. Либо вовсе хранить предаггрегированное состояние в `materialized view` либо крохотной, обновляемой триггерами, табличке.